# How to specify password to connect to Tangasol Coherence Server from .Net

Tags: c#, oracle-coherence

I want to connect to a Tangasol Coherence Server from my C# .Net application. The server is asking for a password to connect. I am not able to find examples of such a scenario. Where do I specify the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution from the following link: http://coherence.oracle.com/display/EXAMPLES/Coherence+Security+Examples#CoherenceSecurityExamples-pit